# Is there any interactive or more user-friendly version of GDB for debugging?

Tags: debugging

Is there any interactive or more user-friendly version (or substitution) of GDB for debugging?

Some people suggested CGDB, but after a few tests I found it buggy and unstable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple graphical frontends for gdb. [GNU DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) and [KGDB](http://www.kdbg.org/) to mention a couple.

[GNU DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/):
[image]

[KGDB](http://www.kdbg.org/):
[image]

**Update:** I failed to mention that gdb actually has a built in text-based user interface if you run it with `gdb -tui`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**GDB Dashboard**

https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard

GDB dashboard uses the [official GDB Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html) and prints the information that you want when GDB stops e.g. after a `next`, like [the native `display` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html).

Vs TUI:

- more robust, as it just prints to stdout instead of putting the shell on a more magic curses state, e.g.:

  - `vi` mode in `.inputrc` causes problems: https://superuser.com/questions/180512/how-to-turn-off-gdb-tui/927728#927728
  - program stdout / stderr breaks your interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291629/gdb-in-tui-mode-how-to-deal-with-stderrs-interaction-with-the-ui
- highly configurable from Python: you can select what you want to output and how big each section is depending on what you are debugging.

  The most useful views are already implemented: source, assembly, registers, stack, memory, threads, expressions... but it should be easy to extend it with any information that is exposed on the GDB Python API.

  TUI only allows showing two of source, assembly and registers and that is it. Unless you want to modify it's C source code of course ;-)

[image]

I believe that GDB should ship with a setup like that out of the box and turned on by default, it would attract much more users that way.

Oh, and the main developer, [Andrea Cardaci](https://github.com/cyrus-and), has been very responsive and awesome. Big kudos.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209534/how-to-highlight-and-color-gdb-output-during-interactive-debugging/17341335#17341335

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of gdb frontends at http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends

This unfortunately gives only further links, but no hints about scope and usability which varies a lot there. I'd recommend to use a frontend that is in active development as gdb itself changes a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDBFrontend: https://github.com/rohanrhu/gdb-frontend

[image: GDBFrontend Screenshot]

Usage video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z44KJDYZOoE

Comment: It seems that you're the creator of the YouTube video. Consider *disclosing that affiliation in the post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).